# How to create google-drive spreadsheet from .csv file?

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api

I`d like to create spreadsheet from .csv file. 
Code:

```
static void Main()
        {
            String CLIENT_ID = "<MY ID>";
            String CLIENT_SECRET = "<MY SECRET>";

            var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
            var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, GetAuthorization);
            var service = new DriveService(auth);

            File body = new File();
            body.Title = "My spread";
            body.Description = "A test spread";
            body.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet";

            byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("spread.csv");
            System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);

            service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet").Upload();
        }

        private static IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient arg)
        {
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile" };
            IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(scopes);
            state.Callback = new Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl);
            Uri authUri = arg.RequestUserAuthorization(state);

            // Request authorization from the user (by opening a browser window):
            Process.Start(authUri.ToString());
            Console.Write("  Authorization Code: ");
            string authCode = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

            // Retrieve the access token by using the authorization code:
            return arg.ProcessUserAuthorization(authCode, state);
        }
```

After inserting file and clicking on it on google-drive page(logged as owner) I get message

*"We're sorry.
The spreadsheet at this URL could not be found. Make sure that you have the right URL and that the owner of the spreadsheet hasn't deleted it"*

When I change MimeType to "text/csv" and insert file, after clicking on it, I get message
 *"No preview available
This item was created with (MyApp'sName), a Google Drive app.
Download this file or use one of the apps you have installed to open it."*

I can also right click on this file(that one created with "text/csv" MimeType) and choose option *"Export to Google Docs"* and this gives me result that I'd like to reach - spreadsheet file with my .csv's file content. But such indirect method doesn`t fully satify me. Is there any method to make spreadsheet file on google drive, with content from .csv file direct from my application?

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know c#, but on the basis it mirrors Java, within the line

> service.Files.Insert(body, stream,
>   "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet").Upload();

you need to insert the equivalent of

> .setConvert(true)

also ...

the mimetype should be "text/csv"

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer :)

How to programmatically convert a file into an appropriate Google Documents format:

```
var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    ...
});

...

FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, _mimeType);
request.Convert = true;
request.Upload();
```